# Rename folder with dashes in its name

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I have a repository with a subfolder named `rest-api`, however, this has brought several issues with import statements. 
I am trying to rename it to something less troublesome, like `rest_api` or just `restapi`.
However when trying to rename from VSCode, I'll get the error:

```
> Error: EPERM: Operation not permitted
```

From the git terminal, `git mv rest-api rest_api` and `git mv -- rest-api rest_api`

will also fail with

```
> fatal: renaming 'rest-api' failed: Permission denied
```

Comment: If on linux/mac use `sudo` if on windows open the terminal as an administrator

Comment: Is the folder open or used somewhere? Did you try running VS Code As Administrator?

Comment: I tried opening VS Code as administrator, which still gave me `EPERM: Operation not permitted`

Comment: Turns out something inside the folder was being used somewhere somehow and thus blocking the renaming. I simply restarted the computer.